# firebase read more information adresse on click

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an address table in firebase with a node "userId" and "the key" (see image). I want to read the information of the element on which the user clicked in my input. I tried from the index to the click. but I still get the whole list.

[Console img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOgnb.jpg)
[Table adresse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO9Zn.jpg)

below my code

Environnement.ts

```
export const ToArrayAdres = snapshot =>{
  let returnArray = [];
  snapshot.forEach( child => {
    let item = child.val();
    item.key = child.key;
    returnArray.push(item);
  });
  return returnArray;
}
```

Single andresse.ts

```
itemsA = [];
  refA = firebase.database().ref('adresse/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid ).orderByChild('key');
  constructor() {
    this.refA.on('value', resp => {
      this.itemsA = ToArrayAdres(resp);
      console.log(this.itemsA);
    })
```

List adresse

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" (click)="editItem(i)">
                <ion-card-content>
                  <div><b>{{item.prenom}} {{item.nom}}</b></div>
                  <:ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Adresse list.ts

```
viewSingAdress(id: number){
    this.router.navigate(['single-adresse/' +id] );
  }
```

Comment: You pass the index (of the ngFor loop) to your your editItem function. Is this what you want? I could imagine you want to pass the firebase id, ie item.key (as this is how you set it in your ToArrayAdres function)

Comment: Yes I want to transmit item.key and display the item information from the key.

Comment: Do you have a solution. otherwise i know it's possible to do that <ion-card * ngFor = "let item of items;" (click) = "editItem (item.key)"> to get the key but how to recover key call

Comment: Can you please share the code of your editItem() method?

Comment: thanks, here is the method  editItem(key){
    this.router.navigate(['single-adresse/'+key ]);
  }

Comment: I get an url like that localhost:8100 /single-address /-LsRW0thSFsTeE2ADuBz